# num of output files is different from num of files that opened

Tags: c

when i run my code the output file is **filename.as.ob.ent**;
but I need output of 3 files **filename.as, filename.ob , filename.ent**.
Why the output is only one file Instead of three?,
and how can I fix it?
(There's 3 calls of `fprintf`).

```
FILE *as;
FILE *ob;
FILE *ent;
char *file_for_as;
char *file_for_ob;
char *file_for_ent;

file_for_as  = argv[1];
file_for_ob  = argv[1];
file_for_ent = argv[1];

strncat(file_for_as, ".as", 4);
strncat(file_for_ob, ".ob", 4);
strncat(file_for_ent, ".ent", 5);

as = fopen(file_for_as, "w");
ob = fopen(file_for_ob, "w");
ent = fopen(file_for_ent, "w");

fprintf(as, "hello this output belong to the .ent file\n");
fprintf(ob, "hello this output belong to the .as file\n");
fprintf(ent, "hello this output belong to the .ob file\n");


fclose(as);
fclose(ob);
fclose(ent);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allocate space for each of the filenames and construct them there.

In your example you have a bunch of pointers that all point to the same place so they all change the same data. It's also undefined behavior since you can't know that there's any space allocated at the end of the `argv` strings for more data. You could be overwriting memory used for something else.

Since this is a simple example I chose 64 as the length assuming the filenames would not be longer than that. If they will be then you should increase that number. You could also add a check for the length of `argv[1]` to make sure it will fit or dynamically allocate the memory. I didn't since this is just a simple example of how to solve your immediate problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("usage: program <base filename>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char file_for_as[64] = { 0 };
    char file_for_ob[64] = { 0 };
    char file_for_ent[64] = { 0 };

    sprintf(file_for_as, "%s.as", argv[1]);
    sprintf(file_for_ob, "%s.ob", argv[1]);
    sprintf(file_for_ent, "%s.ent", argv[1]);

    FILE *as = fopen(file_for_as, "w");
    FILE *ob = fopen(file_for_ob, "w");
    FILE *ent = fopen(file_for_ent, "w");

    fprintf(as, "hello this output belong to the .as file\n");
    fprintf(ob, "hello this output belong to the .ob file\n");
    fprintf(ent, "hello this output belong to the .ent file\n");

    fclose(as);
    fclose(ob);
    fclose(ent);

    return 0;
}
```